# Point cloud data appear in free space in stage_ros simulation

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, stage-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to simulate world model via stage_ros package. However, I found that there are simulated point cloud appearing in the free space, as shown in the figure below.

I found that the ranges of these laser scan points that should not appear are all 5.0m. However, the max range of range sensor is set to 30.0m in the .world file. So I am confused why this happens?[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347736/point-cloud-data-appear-in-free-space-in-stage_ros-simulation/) by [nkuwenjian](https://answers.ros.org/users/52110/nkuwenjian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I have figured out this problem.

I used "rostopic echo /scan" to see the info of LaserScan message, and I found that even if the laser beam does not hit the obstacle, the range value will also be returned. However, the corresponding intensity value is zero. Using the intensity value to filter the point cloud, the correct point cloud data can be obtained.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [nkuwenjian](https://answers.ros.org/users/52110/nkuwenjian/) with karma: 16 on 2020-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0